# How did Java language prevent us from subclassing 'Enum' when it is declared as abstract ?

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors

It is known that Enums in java cannot be subclassed .

My question however is that although the signature of Enum clearly states that it is an abstract class . And abstract classes could be subclassed as opposed to final classes ,

Still how does java compiler prevent us from sub-classing it ?

The signature of Enum class

***public abstract class Enum>  extends Object  implements Comparable, Serializable***

Comment: It's special-cased.

Comment: When mentioning subclassing with `extends ClassType`: _[It is a compile-time error if the `ClassType` names the class `Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)_